# Best way to separate storing of dependent artifacts for projects and plugins

Tags: maven-3, nexus, repository, artifactory, archiva

In maven 3 we can separate the dependent artifacts for projects and plugins.

What is the best way to do this with a repo manager (nexus ...) if you have proxied and hosted repos? Any examples how define this in settings.xml/pom.xml?

Must a duplicate every proxied repo for plugin and project dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Artifactory, you may create [virtual repositories](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) that aggregate "real" (local\remote) repositories and have one virtual repository aggregate only plugin repositories and another to aggregate only standard library repositories.

As you've already guessed, if you must have a strong separation between plugin and lib dependencies from a proxied remote repository, you'll need to create a duplicate definition for each one and add them to their respective virtual repositories.

Once this setup is done, simply reference the URLs of the virtual repositories in your settings.xml\pom.xml